# Is 1/product(k)=product(1/k)?

Tags: products

I'm wondering:
The common product operator is denoted as $ \Pi z_k $ which is simply $z_1*z_2*z_3...z^n$. If you reciprocated that product, it would be $ \frac{1}{ \Pi z_k}$ which is $ \frac{1}{z_1*z_2*z_3...} $. However, that seems like it could be notated as $ \Pi \frac{1}{z_k} $. Is that true? I don't see how it wouldn't be but I've never seen that before.

Comment: Yes it absolutely can.  Be careful though that none of the multiplicands are zero though.

Comment: Thank you so much for using MathJax! Pro tip: instead of using `$\Pi z_k$`, which gives you $\Pi z_k$, you can use `$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}z_k$$` which gives you $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}z_k$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right.  It's the multiplicative analogy of the fact that when summing, $-\sum a_k = \sum (-a_k)$.